# Zero Denominator in Yule's Q-statistics?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, diversity, concept-drift

In  [Concept Drift Adaptation by Exploiting Historical Knowledge](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.03500)
they use **Yule's Q-statistics** to compute diversity between a collection of predictions.

I think the context is not really important. 
I have two arrays of predictions and an array of truth. 
Q-statistics measure the association between the two prediction arrays w.r.t the truth array.

Here's the definition of the Q-statistics:

$$
 Q\left(f_{i}, f_{j}\right)=\frac{N^{11} N^{00}-N^{01} N^{10}}{N^{11} N^{00}+N^{01} N^{10}}
$$

**$N^{11}$** is number of times where pred1 == pred 2 == truth (**both predictions correct**) 
**$N^{00}$** is number of times where pred1 == pred 2 != truth (**both predictions wrong**) 
**$N^{10}$** is number of times where pred1 == truth  != pred 2  (**first prediction correct**) 
**$N^{01}$** is number of times where pred1 != pred 2 == truth (**second prediction correct**)

I cannot figure out which is the value of Q when the **denominator goes to 0.**

If there's only one non-zero values, it means that the two arrays are either  completely equal ($Q=1$, $Q=-1$) either completely different. ($Q=0$).

But what if the only non-zero values are $N^{00}$ and $N^{01}$? Or $N^{11}$ and $N^{10}$?  
 
( Or other similar cases where always only one term from the left part of the denominator and one from the right part. )

**Example:** 
pred_1 = [0,1,1,0,0,0] 
 
pred_2 = [0,1,0,1,1,1] 
truth  = [1,0,0,1,1,1]

This case would lead to a **zero-denominator**, but the two vectors are neither equal neither different.

What's the Q-statistics in those cases?

*edit:* 
This is the way the Q-statistics is used to compute diversity for a collection of predictors: 
$$
\operatorname{div}(S)=1-\frac{1}{\sum_{1 \leq i \neq j \leq m} 1} \sum_{1 \leq i \neq j \leq m} Q\left(f_{i}, f_{j}\right)
$$

Comment: Looks like the statistic is simply undefined in that case.  This would happen when one of the predictors is always right or it is always wrong, in which case association with the other predictor doesn't really seem like the thing you should be quantifying anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Since I need to return a value, do you suggest to just ignore the Q-statistics for a couple of predictors that falls in this category? 
(The way Q is used to compute diversity has been added in the question)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Creosote

> the statistic is simply undefined in that case

It does not make sense to compute an associativity measure if one of the two predictors is completely right or completely wrong.

The couple of predictors that fall in this category can be ignored when computing diversity.